# Emulate native touch in Android Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am working on an Android Cordova app where I want to programmatically open the soft keyboard when the page is loaded (keypad instead of regular keyboard).
There already is a plugin that should do exactly what I need
([Cordova Android Focus Plugin](https://github.com/46cl/cordova-android-focus-plugin)), but I can't get it to work as intended.

My code to Focus the Element 'Stunden' looks like this:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    cordova.plugins.Focus.focus('Stunden');
}
</script>

.
.
.

<body onload="onLoad()">
```

When the code is executed on the device I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Focus' of undefined

So I guess the code is executed before the Plugin is loaded completely, but I could not find another method than "deviceready" to wait for it.
Thanks for your help already!

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling I found out how to get it to work:

In the [Android Focus Plugin](https://github.com/46cl/cordova-android-focus-plugin) Docs it says that you can set the focus on an element by calling the function

```
cordova.plugins.Focus.focus(element);
```

Replacing (element) with ("Stunden") breaks the function, instead defining a variable

```
element = document.getElementByID('Stunden')
```

does the trick. This might be really basic, but in case someone stumbles over this I will just leave it here.

The working code then looks like this

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
var element = document.getElementById('Stunden')
    cordova.plugins.Focus.focus(element);
}
</script>

.
.
.

<body onload="onLoad()">
```